# Forecasting of multiple related time series

Tags: time-series, lstm

I would like to know if there are any methods to forecast multiple time series that are related ? I heard of LSTM but of what I can see it's more to forecast one time series and not several at the same time but I'm not sure. Any ideas are welcome, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use vector autoregressive models to do this, please see the following resource: [11.2 Vector Autoregressive models VAR(p) models](https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat510/lesson/11/11.2)

This model is used for multivariate time series, and works by using each variable as a previous lag of itself as well as other variables.

In this regard, you could choose to model the multiple time series using statsmodels as per this example: [statsmodels: Vector Autoregressions tsa.vector_ar](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/vector_ar.html)

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the late reply but I'm definitely going to give it a try